# Log Application Insight custom dimensions using serilog

Tags: logging, azure-application-insights, asp.net-core-3.1, serilog, .net-5

I would like to enrich the serilog trace message with some customized information (for example the user role, the business solution..) and I would like to see those properties into the Application Insight "Custom Dimension" field. I tried to look around but I didn't find a proper solution. I'm using ASP.NET Core 3.1

Comment: Ok, probably I found a possible solution to my own question. [Here](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-applicationinsights#how-custom-properties-are-logged) they suggest to use the following 
`var position = new { Latitude = 25, Longitude = 134 };
var elapsedMs = 34;
var numbers = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4 };

Logger.Information("Processed {@Position} in {Elapsed:000} ms., str {str}, numbers: {numbers}", position, elapsedMs, "test", numbers);`
to log custom params into "CustomDimension". Seem it works perfectly. What do you think?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As op said in the comment, there is a [suggestion on this case](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-applicationinsights#how-custom-properties-are-logged).

Basicly，when we use `serilog with application insights`， we usually set custom dimensions like this:

```
var position = new { Latitude = 25, Longitude = 134 }; 
var elapsedMs = 34; 
var numbers = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4 };  
Logger.Information("Processed {@Position} in {Elapsed:000} ms., str {str}, numbers: {numbers}", position, elapsedMs, "test", numbers);
```